# if else shows same result always in c++

Tags: c++

hi here is my code and it always show result for first if statement. For instance, when i write 56, it shows 43 even i choose whether venus or mars. why ?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int weight2;
  int mass;
 string planet;
  
 double mars = 0.39;
  double venus = 0.78;
 
  
  std::cout << "Your weight on Earth:";
  std::cin >> mass;
  std::cout << "Which planet you wanna fight on:";
  std::cin >> planet;
  if (planet == "venus" || "Venus") {
    mass = mass*0.78;
    std::cout << mass;
  }
  else if (planet == "mars" || "Mars") {
    mass = mass*0.39;
    std::cout << mass;
  }
  
  else {
    std::cout << "Are you in a paralel universe?";
  }
```

Comment: `(planet == "venus" || "Venus") {` -> `(planet == "venus" || planet == "Venus") {`

Comment: Stuff like `if (planet == "venus" || "Venus") {` doesn't work; you need `if (planet == "venus" || planet == "Venus") {` (and likewise for Mars).

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure your constant for Venus is off - I think it's heavier than that ;-)

Comment: also take out `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Validate EVERY input, e.g. `if (!(std::cin >> mass)) { std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n"; return 1; }`